# The "Primitive" Minister

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading H. G. Wells‘s "The wonderful visit" and struggle to understand the expression *"Primitive" minister*, which appears without much context, unless it is to be given later. The passage reads:

> And Sandy Bright went to talk the matter over with Mr. Jekyll, the “Primitive” minister, and the ploughman told old Hugh and afterwards the vicar of Siddermorton.

I suspect it is some pun on "prime minister", but I don’t see it. It is the first mention of Mr. Jekyll and nothing has been said of his primitive nature or occupation.

The full ebook is available [here](https://standardebooks.org/ebooks/h-g-wells/the-wonderful-visit), free of charge.

Comment: It might be [foreshadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreshadowing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Primitive" minister is the pastor of a non-conformist<sup>†</sup> congregation which rejects religious practices and doctrines which were not embraced by the conjectural "Primitive Church", as evidenced in Biblical accounts.

---

<sup>†</sup> That is, a Protestant congregation outside the "established" or state-sponsored Church of England. The *vicar of Siddermorton* would be the pastor of a CofE congregation.